# Logcat error. Issue when trying to change a textview value

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, textview, logcat

Probably a simple error but the logcat is confusing me. I have just passed a variable 'name' from a listview to this activity and want to change the title textview to that variable using... 'detailedsocietyname' being used as the textview ID in the XML file

```
final TextView changetitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailedsocietyname);
changetitle.setText(name);
```

When that didn't work I tried to use a toast to test it instead using

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The issue is that when the listview choice is chosen the app shuts down.... if all the code above is commented out, it works but the default screen title of 'example' is shown.

Thanks in advance,

Full Code

```
package com.apolloapps.ntusoc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DetailedScreen extends Activity {

final TextView changetitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailedsocietyname);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String name = in.getStringExtra(("name"));//gets name from intent

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    changetitle.setText(name);





    this.setContentView(R.layout.detailedscreen);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detailedscreen, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

EDIT: First activity Intent Code

```
final String selected = (String) parent.getSelectedItem();
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailedScreen.class);
i.putExtra("name", selected);
startActivity (i);
```

SOLUTION: Use

```
final String name = items[position];
```

Instead of

```
final String selected = (String) parent.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: you are searching for the view way before you call setContentView, how do you expect it to be found ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.detailedscreen);  //set the layout here

final TextView changetitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailedsocietyname); //then get id of any view
    Intent in = getIntent();
    String name = in.getStringExtra("name");//gets name here and make sure in first activity you are not passing empty string 

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    changetitle.setText(name);
}
```

**EDIT**

if in first activity you passed string like this:

```
intent.putExtra("name", selected);
```

then get it in second activity like this

```
name=in.getStringExtra("name");
```

your toast message is correct you can check this by displaying a simple text like this :

```
  Toast.makeText(this,"Toast works fine " , 3000).show();
```

see this [example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) how to pass string to another activity.

Comment: Cheers for the reply, I tried that out but the toast and title now show up blank....

Comment: Check this..

[From JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @Shiv I know the toast is working fine... I will put the intent code from the first activity in the question because the problem might be there, if you don't mind taking a long. Cheers

Comment: @ZachRyall-its ok but better if you see the example and edit i have done in my answer and solve it

Comment: @Shiv Oh sorry, I have edit my code to yours. Does the piece of code that I edited into the original question actually work or pass in an empty variable... that could be the issue.. Thanks

Comment: yes problem is the string which you are passing ...just pass a simpe "hello" string and see if it works or you can debug your code to see what values you are getting in "selected" string

Comment: Of course, simple test, duhh... I replaced the variable in the first activity with 'hello' instead of the 'parent.getSelectedItem(); Now it works so the error is in that line, Thanks

Comment: Found a bit of code that does the same thing in a different way.... Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your onCreate() method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detailedscreen);

    //your code
}
```

Comment: if the toast code is un-commented, it shows up blank and if the 'change title' code is un-commented, it shuts down the app...

Answer (score 0):

- First of all always make sure you call setContentView() before your call anything like findViewById()

You did not post the code where you sent the string to this activity but I assume either

-1. that the value you send is empty, 
-2. you do not send the value
-3. the StringExtra name is not the same in this AND the previous activity i.e. "name"